# Agrupar filas en select múltiple (ORACLE)

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, sql

mi consulta es teniendo la siguiente tabla, con filas duplicadas a excepción del ID:

```
ID   Col1   Col2   Col3
--   ----   ----   ----
1      7     46    12  
2      7     46    12
3     245     1    792
4     245     1    792
```

Y lo que quiero es que me muestre:

```
ID   Col1   Col2   Col3
--   ----   ----   ----
1      7     46    12  
3     245     1    792
```

¿De qué forma podría lograrlo? la query que estoy usando llama a múltiples columnas (más de 20).

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón para las filas duplicadas? Mi primera reacción es "limpia la tabla, solucionarás tu problema actual y te evitarás muchos más adelante".

Comment: en este caso hay que dejar el ID, no puedo limpiar la tabla.

Comment: y cual ID hay que dejar?

Comment: el mínimo, en este caso 1 y 3

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas la cláusula `GROUP BY` y la columna que quieras filtrar... quedaría algo así:

```
select * 
from tabla
group by col1
```

de esta forma saldrán todos los datos de la tabla y solo repetirá una vez los datos de la columna1

Comment: Si haces `group by`, solo se pueden incluir en el `select` los campos indicados en el `group by`.

Comment: claro, pero no puedo sacar el parámetro ID

Comment: si podes.. el problema es cual de todos los Id queres @user2820116